# Why is my jQuery function not being called correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsubmit

I have this jQuery function that is using another jQuery library called html5csv.js (which explains some of the CSV stuff you will see)

Here is it:

```
function validateNewQuiz()
{
    CSV.begin("#upload_csv").go(function(e,D)
    { 
        if (e) 
        {
            return console.log(e); 
            alert("Sorry, an error occured");
        }

        var s = "";


        for (var i = 0; i <= D.rows.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            s +=D.rows[i].join(',');
            s += "\n";
        }

        var fullString = s;

        if(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/.test(fullString))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

Here is how I am trying to call my function, from an `onsubmit` within my form:

```
<form method="post" action="createplay.php" onsubmit="return validateNewQuiz();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

My function has been thoroughly tested, along with my regex to make sure it was working. When I decided to implement it into my large document, and wrap it around `function validateNewQuiz(){ //my function here }` , it stopped working.

I did not make my tests with the `onsubmit` part within my form either.

Does anyone have any suggestions to why my form is always submitting, even when my function should be returning `false`?

Comment: You are returning `true` or `false` from the callback function that is passed into `go()`, so `validateNewQuiz` is actually returning undefined. If the CSV library is asynchronous (and looks like it is), you won't be able to use it this way in on an onsubmit handler.

Comment: @MattGreer - Do you have any other alternatives then? I need to validate my form client side with Javascript before it is posted to my `PHP`.

Comment: your outer function validateNewQuiz() isnt actually returning anything. You are only returning the value of your CSV function, but then doing nothing with it. Have your validateNewQuiz() fn actually return the value of the CSV function.

Comment: @gos1 - Could you post an example of that within the answer section please?

Comment: You have jQuery - why are you adding inline event handlers?

Comment: exact duplicate of your earlier question [_Why is my jQuery/Javascript function not being called correctly with onsubmit?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427511/why-is-my-jquery-javascript-function-not-being-called-correctly-with-onsubmit)

Comment: @gos1 JavaScript functions always return something. If there is no return statement they return `undefined`

Comment: Done. @Matt Greer Thanks. I meant that it should have been returning a true or false value, but you are absolutely right, as the question was written, validateNewQuiz() is always returning undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onsubmit` event handler allows the submission to proceed if it is passed a `true` value by the validation function, and does not allow the submission to proceed if it receives a `false` value. In your case, the inner function is returning a true or false value, but this value is not being passed to the outer `validateNewQuiz` function, so the true/false result of the validation is not being passed to the `onsubmit` event handler. To fix this, just return the value of the `CSV` function.

```
function validateNewQuiz()
{
    var csvValidation = CSV.begin("#upload_csv").go(function(e,D)
    { 
        if (e) 
        {
            return console.log(e); 
            alert("Sorry, an error occured");
        }

        var s = "";


        for (var i = 0; i <= D.rows.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            s +=D.rows[i].join(',');
            s += "\n";
        }

        var fullString = s;

        if(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/.test(fullString))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    });
    return csvValidation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a button that would be calling your function:

```
<button onclick="validateNewQuiz()">Submit</button>
```

... and submitting the form once it is validated:

```
function validateNewQuiz()
{
    CSV.begin("#upload_csv").go(function(e,D)
    { 

        //...

        if(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/.test(fullString))
        {
            $("form").submit();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```