# Why is my jQuery/Javascript function not being called correctly with onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, csv, onsubmit

I have this jQuery function that is using another jQuery library called html5csv.js (which explains some of the CSV stuff you will see)

Here is it:

```
function validateNewQuiz()
{
    CSV.begin("#upload_csv").go(function(e,D)
    { 
        if (e) 
        {
            return console.log(e); 
            alert("Sorry, an error occured");
        }

        var s = "";


        for (var i = 0; i <= D.rows.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            s +=D.rows[i].join(',');
            s += "\n";
        }

        var fullString = s;

        if(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/.test(fullString))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

Here is how I am trying to call my function, from an `onsubmit` within my form:

```
<form method="post" action="createplay.php" onsubmit="return validateNewQuiz();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

My function has been thoroughly tested, along with my regex to make sure it was working. When I decided to implement it into my large document, and wrap it around `function validateNewQuiz(){ //my function here }` , it stopped working.

I did not make my tests with the onsubmit part within my form either.

I tried fixing it two ways. One way was like this, splitting them into two functions:

```
var fullString = "";
CSV.begin("#upload_csv").go(function(e,D)
{ 
    if (e) 
    {
        return console.log(e); 
        alert("Sorry, an error occured");
    }

    var s = "";


    for (var i = 0; i <= D.rows.length - 1; i++) 
    {
        s +=D.rows[i].join(',');
        s += "\n";
    }

    fullString = s;
});


function validateNewQuiz()
{
    if(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/.test(fullString))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the second way, by added the `return` outside of the CSV part:

```
var fullString = "";
function validateNewQuiz()
{
    CSV.begin("#upload_csv").go(function(e,D)
    { 
        if (e) 
        {
            return console.log(e); 
            alert("Sorry, an error occured");
        }

        var s = "";


        for (var i = 0; i <= D.rows.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            s +=D.rows[i].join(',');
            s += "\n";
        }

        fullString = s;
    });

    if(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/.test(fullString))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to why my form is always submitting, even when my function should be returning `false`?

Here is another edit that I tried to make, although it is still submitting to my PHP and the `console` messages are not being displayed since that page is being submitted to PHP, therefore reloading

```
jQuery("#newQuizID").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    CSV.begin("#upload_csv").go(function(e,D)
    { 
        if (e) 
        {
            return console.log(e); 
            alert("Sorry, an error occured");
        }

        var s = "";


        for (var i = 0; i <= D.rows.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            s +=D.rows[i].join(',');
            s += "\n";
        }

        var fullString = s;

        if(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/.test(fullString))
        {
            console.log("Working");
            jQuery("#form-step2").submit();
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Not Working");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: well inside the `go` callback the `returns` only return true/false within the callback function so they have to be outside it as with your second try, and is the `go` function an asynchronous function? If so the check against `fullString` wont work because it wont have been set, because the function returns immediately and lets the work happen in the background making `fullString` not set at the time of checking.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - I believe it is an asynchronous function, yes. Is there another way around this?

Comment: see my answer, you want to use a click handler instead of onsubmit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html5csv puts a event handler on the file input so it only triggers when a file is added so you need to set a valid flag somewhere and then check it before submitting

```
function checkValidCSV(e) {
    var isValid = jQuery("#form-step2").data("hasValidData");
    if( typeof(isValid) != "undefined" && isValid ) {
        jQuery("#form-step2").submit();
    } else {
        //Do whatever invalid data cals you want to do here
        alert("csv file was invalide so i am not submitting the form");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function csvFileLoaded(e,D) {
    if (e) {
        return console.log(e); 
        alert("Sorry, an error occured");
    }

    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i <= D.rows.length - 1; i++) {
        s +=D.rows[i].join(',');
        s += "\n";
    }
    var fullString = s;
    if(/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]+\n){3}$/.test(fullString)){
        console.log("Valid Data");
        jQuery("#form-step2").data("hasValidData",true);
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid Data");
        jQuery("#form-step2").data("hasValidData",false);
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    CSV.begin("#upload_csv").go(csvFileLoaded);
    jQuery("#newQuizID").click(checkValidCSV);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. One question, what is stopping my PHP from posting to itself since this is within my form `method="post" action="createplay.php"`

Comment: '.submit' just programmatically submits the form instead of manually so the url in "action" is still used.

Comment: So what is stopping the `action` from being used when the `submit` button is pressed at the beginning before the Javascript is even called?

Comment: in the `click` event you will see `e.preventDefault()`, e here is a reference to the event object, this prevents the default action of the event from happening, in this case it prevents the submission of the form, click event happens before the submit event, and since `preventDefault` is called in the click event, it prevents `submit` from being triggered.

Comment: I just tested it. Although, it is still posting to my PHP... Any suggestions?

Comment: can you add an edit to your question showing how you implemented the code

Comment: I added it to the end of my question along with a short blurb.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36192/discussion-between-patrick-evans-and-fizzix)

Comment: Patrick, do you happen to know why my form is now not submitting the CSV file to my PHP anymore?