# how do i export a .csv file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a dynamically generated table into a .csv file, but when i click on export button i get an error: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'CSV' is undefined
i am using this example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrPaulBrewer/raaaW/4/)  it works fine here but when i migrate the code i get an error:

This is my jquery that does exporting on a button click:

```
   $('.btnDownload').on('click', function () {
            $(function () {
                CSV.begin('#showTable').download('file.csv').go();
            });
[MY JSFIDDLE][2] this how my code is, in my project i am using jquery-2.0.3.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a `script` tag with `Src="http://www.csvscript.com/dev/html5csv.js"`
I think you are not doing that.

Comment: I'll suggest you to save the js. And use the js locally.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what external javascript library you use but in your code:
-Make sure that you have a reference to your CSV-function file.

Perhaps: `<script src="html5csv.js " />` (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427511/why-is-my-jquery-javascript-function-not-being-called-correctly-with-onsubmit))